# InnoDB Performance on primary index added/altering

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

So I have a huge update where I have to insert around 40gb data into an innodb table. Its taking quite a while, so Im wondering which method would be the fastest (and more importantly why, as I could just do a split test).

Method 1)

a) Insert all rows
b) create ALTER TABLE su_tmp_matches ADD PRIMARY KEY ( id )

Method 2)

a) ALTER TABLE su_tmp_matches ADD PRIMARY KEY ( id )
b) Insert all rows

Currently we are using method 1, but the step b) seems to take a shitload of time. So Im wondering if there is any implication of the size here (40gb - 5 million rows).

---- so I decided to test this as well ---
Pretty quick brand new mysql server - loads and loads of ram, and fast ram, fast discs as well, and pretty tuned up (we have more than 5000 requests per second on one pieces):

1,6 mio rows / 6gb data:

81 seconds to "delete" a primary index

550 seconds to "add" a primary index (after data is added)

120 seconds to create a copy of the table with the primary index create BEFORE data insert

80 seconds to create a copy of the table without the primary index (which then is 550 seconds to create afterwards)

Seems pretty absurd - question is, if indexes are the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html) :

> InnoDB does not have a special optimization for separate index
>   creation the way the MyISAM storage engine does. Therefore, it does
>   not pay to export and import the table and create indexes afterward.
>   The fastest way to alter a table to InnoDB is to do the inserts
>   directly to an InnoDB table.

It seems to me that adding the constraint of unicity before the insert could only help the engine if your column having a primary key is an autoincremented integer. But I really doubt there would be a notable difference.

A useful recommendation :

> During the conversion of big tables, increase the size of the InnoDB
>   buffer pool to reduce disk I/O, to a maximum of 80% of physical
>   memory. You can also increase the sizes of the InnoDB log files.

*EDIT : as by experience MySQL doesn't always perform as expected from the documentation performance-wise, I think any benchmark you do on this would be interesting, even if not a definite answer per se.*

Comment: thx for the answer. Ill try doing a benchmark on it just to see whats going on :) Ill post results tomorrow. "InnoDB does not have a special optimization for separate index creation the way the MyISAM storage engine does" this part was particularly helpful, as most myisam is going out the drain after we upgraded mysql to .5 :)